# Use non-optional as Binding expecting optional: Error: Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Int>' to expected argument type Binding<(some Hashable)?>

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have some code which fails to compile.
Here is the simplified relevant part:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var currentIndex: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                // [...]
            }
            .scrollPosition(id: $currentIndex)
            
            Button(action: { currentIndex += 1 }) { Text("Next") }
        }
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
>>>> .scrollPosition(id: $currentIndex)
- Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Int>' to expected argument type 'Binding<(some Hashable)?>'
- Generic parameter 'some Hashable' could not be inferred
```

`Int` is definitely `Hashable`.

For some reason the compiler can't figure out that the `Binding<Int>` should be acceptable as an argument expecting `Binding<(some Hashable)?>` .

The issue seems to be the `Optional` part of `Binding<(some Hashable)?>` .

Making my state optional - `@State var currentIndex: Int? = 0` - solves the issue!

This of course is really annoying, especially if this state is also used in other places which can happily accept a non-optional.

I know I can make it explicitly unwrapped  (`Int!`) but this is also not ideal, as it still requires unwrapping in some contexts (e.g. if used as part of an `.onChange` closure) and overall feels hacky and unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out wrapping the argument in `Binding(...)` solves the issue without the need of making the `@State` optional:

Chang this:

`.scrollPosition(id: $currentIndex)`

to this:

`.scrollPosition(id: Binding($currentIndex))`

Comment: Creating a Binding to a State looks like a really bad workaround, why not make the property optional instead? Nil seems to be a legit value if there is no view to scroll to.

Comment: Of course if `nil` did make sense in my domain, it would be totally fine (in fact, required), for the property to be optional. But in this case, it will never be `nil`, so making it optional is not ideal, just to satisfy the compiler. I don't understand what you mean by _"Creating a Binding to a State looks like a really bad workaround"_ - this is the basics of data flow in SwiftUI - `$` creates a binding from a state (because the projected value of a `@State` property wrapper is the `Binding`). `Binding<$somethng>` is the same as `$somethng`, we're just helping the compiler a bit.

Answer (score -1):

You already know the answer, you have a few ways to handle the `currentIndex` property. Choose the approach that aligns best with your specific use case and coding preferences.

1. Make currentIndex Optional with a Default Value, This allows you to use currentIndex with an optional value and provides a default of 0.

```
    @State var currentIndex: Int? = 0
```

2. Wrap the Argument in Binding(...), This approach involves using the Binding initializer to create a Binding<Int?>.

```
.scrollPosition(id: Binding($currentIndex))
```

3. Less preferred approach, This combines having a non-optional State property with the flexibility of an optional binding.

```
    @State var currentIndex: Int = 0

    var optionalBinding: Binding<Int?> {
        Binding(get: { self.currentIndex }, set: { self.currentIndex = $0 ?? 0 })
    }
```